# ng2-carouselamos left and right icons not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I am using ng2-carouselamos

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-carouselamos

here I just copied html template and but clickable events are not working,as there is no ts file in the documentation,so that will work

I am not sure,I need to write something in ts file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `listOfItems` in typescript if you not set then `ng2-carouselamos` doesn't work.

here is working example: [ng2-carouselamos demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fssh6z)